# Adding an image in the menu bar with RefineryCMS

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, refinerycms

I am new to RefineryCMS and I need to put an image inspaite of the site name in the menu bar, but i did not witch path to put.

This is my essai:

```
<header id="header">
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="banner" >
    <div class="navbar-header" style= "height: 86px">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
       <a class="navbar-brand" ><%= link_to(image_tag("../assets/images/logo3.png" , id:"logosT"), refinery.root_path, class: 'navbar-brand' ) %></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <%= Refinery::Pages::MenuPresenter.new(refinery_menu_pages, self).to_html %>
    </div>
```

I also tried to put it in the system folder and put this path

```
system/refinery/images/2015/01/13/3h4r68bcyr_logo3.png
```

but still not working
Could you please tell me how to put an image in spite of the site name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the image in `app/assets/images` and use the following:

`<%= link_to(image_tag("logo3.png" , id:"logosT"), refinery.root_path, class: 'navbar-brand' ) %>`